# Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to print the list of a singly linked list that I referred to in [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309359/creating-a-singly-linked-list-in-c). It works, but I do get the compiler warnings:

> `Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type`

(on declaration of start = head) and

> `return discards qualifiers from pointer target type`

(on return statement) in this code:

```
/* Prints singly linked list and returns head pointer */
LIST *PrintList(const LIST *head) 
{
    LIST *start = head;

    for (; start != NULL; start = start->next)
        printf("%15s %d ea\n", head->str, head->count);

    return head;
}
```

I am using XCode. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just FYI I've had gcc print unidentified warnings like this that I think are controlled by `-Wwrite-strings`. There's `-Wdiscarded-qualifiers`, `-Wcast-qual` and clang's `-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers` which look related too.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It's this part:

```
LIST *start = head;
```

The parameter for the function is a pointer to a constant, `const LIST *head`; this means you cannot change what it is pointing to. However, the pointer above is to non-const; you could dereference it and change it.

It needs to be `const` as well:

```
const LIST *start = head;
```

The same applies to your return type.

---

All the compiler is saying is: "Hey, you said to the caller 'I won't change anything', but you're opening up opportunities for that."

Comment: Dumb question, but what does a const return type look like?  I tried searching on the web, and I can't seem to find one.

Comment: @Crystal - `const LIST *PrintList(const LIST *head) { ... }`

Comment: `The parameter for the function is a constant pointer` - incorrect. `const LIST *head` declares head as a pointer to a constant LIST. See: http://c-faq.com/decl/constparm.html -- perhaps this is just a misunderstanding in the wording.

Comment: Love it when it gets explained in natural language, as if the compiler could talk. Great explanation!

Answer (score 29):

In following function, would get the warning that you encountered with.

```
void test(const char *str) {
  char *s = str;
}
```

There are 3 choices:

1. Remove the const modifier of param:

   ```
   void test(char *str) {
     char *s = str;
   }
   ```
2. Declare the target variable also as const:

   ```
   void test(const char *str) {
     const char *s = str;
   }
   ```
3. Use a type convert:

   ```
   void test(const char *str) {
     char *s = (char *)str;
   }
   ```

Comment: Good answer in my opinion. One question that I have @Eric is about the third choice: Doesn't it prevent the aim of the `const`?  The programmer can now change the value of `str` with the pointer `s`, doesn't he? Or we are satisfied with the fact he "delcared" about that by using the type convert `(char *)str`?