# Passing Argument 1 discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv

My main function is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    huffenc(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler returns the warning:

`huffenc.c:76: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘huffenc’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type`

For reference, `huffenc` takes a `char*` input, and the function is executed, with the sample input "senselessness" via `./huffenc senselessness`

What could this warning mean?

Comment: You say that `huffenc` takes a `char *`, but you're passing it a `char const *`...

Comment: Really? Does this mean I have to use type coercion on it?

Comment: I think you could refer to this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316387/initialization-discards-qualifiers-from-pointer-target-type

Comment: Just define main without the `const`.

Comment: Well you could, but that's inelegant (and potentially dangerous).  A better solution is to figure out **why** `huffenc` needs a non-const pointer, and change it to const if possible.

Comment: That's an incorrect definition of `main` anyway, just do it right to begin with; `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @EdS. I would not call it incorrect, you can add `const` pretty much anywhere as you want.

Comment: @Kay: Well, the standard is pretty clear that the definition of main is either `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or `int main(void)`.  It goes on to say that *"5.1.2.2.1 Program startup: The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array **shall
be modiﬁable by the program**..."* So, I *would* call it incorrect.  It will work of course, but why?  When have either of the two standard definitions led to buggy programs?

Comment: @EdS. well, I know that the program may update argv and the strings passed in argv as long as you don't violate the bounds. Either way, `int main(int, const char**)` may not be elegant, but it is definitely not "incorrect" (it's just the word that I don't like).

Comment: @Kay: Well, I suppose "non-standard" or "not idiomatic" may have been better, but when the standard tells you  what your function signature should be... you should take its advice.

Comment: @EdS. acknowledged, I agree with that wording. :-)

Comment: @Kay: Section 5.1.2.2.1 of the ISO C standard specifies two standard definitions for `main` (quoted above by Ed S.).  It doesn't say anywhere that you can arbitrarily add `const`, and I'm not at all sure that a conforming compiler is required to accept it if you do. If you have an argument that adding `const` is valid (i.e., must be accepted by any conforming hosted C compiler), I'd be interested in seeing it. (Just noticed how hold this question is; not sure why it showed up on the front page for me.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means that you're passing a `const` argument to a function which takes a non-`const` argument, which is potentially bad for obvious reasons.

`huffenc` probably doesn't need a non-`const` argument, so it should take a `const char*`.  However, your definition of `main` is non-standard.

The C99 standard Section 5.1.2.2.1 (Program startup) states:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be deﬁned with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-deﬁned manner.

And goes on to say...

> ...The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array **shall
>   be modiﬁable by the program**, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.