# About some settings of strtok()

Tags: c, strtok

This is the warning I am getting:

```
passing argument 1 of ‘strtok’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target 
type [enabled by default]
```

I wanted to disable this default operation can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us code which triggers the error with some context. Check [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok` works in-place: it needs to tokenize the string you passed to it.

Of course, you could force non-const cast but that would violate the contract. What if the caller expects to re-use the passed string after your operation? So it's a no-go.

So if you have some constant string, you have to make a copy before using it, for instance using `strdup`

```
char *copy = strdup(my_const_char);
toks = strtok(copy," ",NULL);
...
```

In the end, you have all your tokens in separate pointers, with memory already allocated and held by `copy`. Once you don't need the tokens anymore, `free`ing `copy` is all that you need to clean it up.

Note that a generic answer to this const qualifier question is: [Passing Argument 1 discards qualifiers from pointer target type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398580/passing-argument-1-discards-qualifiers-from-pointer-target-type)